# How to handle UIPageViewController with text at one page and image at another page

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want to display one array of images coming from webservice at right side even nos pages and another array with no of texts coming from webservice at left side odd nos pages.

I used below sample to make my task but it is using one view.But i want to handle with two view controllers displaying text of view controller at left side and image of another view controller at right side shown below.I am doing ipad application.

i used this sample.I am attaching link of it below.

http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/

[image: Here is the sample image i want to work with UIPageViewController]

Any samples or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have tried to implement a page view controller that shows two pages at once? What is your specific problem?

Comment: This is the screen shot taken from my simulator.My app is executing like this.The sample i tried is taking single view with imageview.I want to show images at even page side and not to display left side.As every page is displaying images when i hide the image at odd pages then that hidden images is not showing anymore.So i want to show all images only at right side only .

Comment: What is this "sample" you tried? Are you following a tutorial, or using someone else's code? Have you tried to implement a double page  UIPageController on your own?

Comment: I am attaching the sample link that i used.I applied background and made some modifications to that sample based on my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

it can also be done in one view controller by using a for loop and inside use

```
if(i%2==0) {
    blah blah...
} else if (i%3==0) {
    blah blah...
}
```